# Is there a way to suppress a console error if the ng-src image attributes throws an error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I have the following code in angular.

```
<img class="img-circle image-stroke" ng-src="{{person.photo}}" onerror="this.src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/9/4/c/12198090531909861341man%20silhouette.svg.hi.png'"></img>
```

I'm getting a person object back from the database with a `photo` property that contains the url of the person's photo. The problem is, sometimes this value will be null. As you can see, I've handled it with an `onerrror` attribute in the tag, so whenever it is null, and `ng-src` throws an error, it'll fall back to a default image.

The problem is, it will still throw the following error in the console.

`GET http://localhost:3000/module/seasons/person.photo 404 (Not Found)`

Is there any way to suppress this error? In production, it's pretty likely there will be 12 or 13 people without a photo value at a time and I don't want my bosses to see 12 or 13 errors in the console, even if nothing is breaking on the actual site.

Comment: I doubt it, other than making it not possible for the error to occur in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could render only if the src isn't null and otherwise render the backup image:

```
<img ng-if="person.photo" class="img-circle image-stroke" ng-src="person.photo"></img>
<img ng-if="!person.photo" class="img-circle image-stroke" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/9/4/c/12198090531909861341man%20silhouette.svg.hi.png"></img>
```